# MS SQL query with multiple search criteria across rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have below table and SQL query written, this query should not return any result but its returning `ID = 1` , what is wrong with the SQL query? Can anyone please help?

** Note `balance` data type is `decimal` rest are `varchar`

```
ID  code    balance level
1   C   150.00  
1   P   40027.42    F
1   P   40027.42    F
```

```
select distinct ID from table
(
(code = 'P' and balance = 40027.42 and level = 'F') or
(code  = 'C' and balance = 151.00 )
)
group by ID
having count(ID) >=2
```

Comment: Based on your `having` clause of `count(ID) >=2`, this query is returning the `id` for rows that meet the `where` clauses and have more than 1 row, which would be `ID = 1`. Since you have two rows for `ID = 1` that meet the clause of `(code = 'P' and balance = 40027.42 and level = 'F')`

Also, `distinct` is not needed for this query.

Comment: Having clause is ok but questions is about the balance value for code C , table has 150.00 and my query has 151.00 so query should not return any result but it still it’s ignoring the 151.00

Comment: I see that, but you are ignoring the fact that you have _two rows_ that meet this crtieria: `(code = 'P' and balance = 40027.42 and level = 'F')` Since you have two rows that meet that critieria, it passes the having clause of `having count(ID) >=2`. _greater than or equal to 2_

Comment: My bad , I see that now. Thanks ... is there a way to modify this query to consider only one record by ID so that in this query second set of condition with code C also gets evaluated by query ?

Comment: Pls provide if you have any suggestion on above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to count the same `code` twice, you can use `count(distinct code)`:

```
select ID 
from t
where (code = 'P' and balance = 40027.42 and level = 'F') 
  or (code  = 'C' and balance = 151.00 )
group by ID
having count(distinct code) >=2
```

---

If you want to only count a distinct set of values once, you can use a derived table/subquery to `select distinct` rows:

```
select ID 
from (
  select distinct id, code, balance, level 
  from t
  ) as s
where (code = 'P' and balance = 40027.42 and level = 'F') 
  or (code  = 'C' and balance = 151.00 )
group by ID
having count(ID) >=2
```

rextester demo for both: http://rextester.com/LBKO57534